# How to read outlook mail item into R

Tags: r

I am trying to read an outlook mail item into `R`, that is saved in my the harddisk (This is saved in .msg format). But not able to do so. Can someone please help me in understanding, how I can do the same? I loaded the `tm.plugin.mail` library for the same.

```
library(tm.plugin.mail)

obj <- readMail(DateFormat="%m %d %Y %H:%M", mail="Crux_info_Detail.msg")
```

When I say obj, it is not giving any content of the file. What is that I missed here? How can I read the mail item into R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an [r] question. Nor is it a [tm] question. You don't know the format so you are not ready to code in R. It's an [outlook] question. Get the format spec, then come back for assistance in parsing.

Comment: Sorry if my question lead to any confusion. But, it is a `R` question only. I want to load the outlook item with `.msg` extension into `R`

Comment: Read the help: `?readMail`. It is a generator function, not meant to be used in the way you did. Try `readMail(DateFormat="%m %d %Y %H:%M")(mail="Crux_info_Detail.msg")`, but you might need to look at how it works in more detail to use it correctly.

Comment: You're going to need to use something like [MSGConvert](http://www.matijs.net/software/msgconv/) to go from `msg` to `mbox` format before using `tm`/`readMail`

Answer (score 0):

Just posting as an answer hrbrmstr reply:

"You're going to need to use something like MSGConvert to go from msg to mbox format before using tm/readMail" and to comment on top of it, you need to know the input specifications made by MSGConvert. There have been some updates since then, and better take a look at the new functionality here:

https://github.com/mvz/email-outlook-message-perl